# Aviation — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

> Update: This will be shipping this week. Enjoy your swag when it gets to you!

**We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!**

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

Comment: I always knew being an aviation nerd would pay off one day... I just didn't realise it would include stickers!

Comment: @JNat I noted that [Sponge Bob](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/700/sponge-bob) who took the initiative of proposing this site in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation) is just outside the top 72. Since he is the founding father of this site, could you consider sending him the top user swag as well?

Comment: They've been included, @DeltaLima. But thanks for keeping an eye out! ;)

Comment: best.day.ever! I love swag! I shall wear this with pride! (also just looked at the rankings...looks like I squeaked in! I am currently in CFI training, so I hope to be contributing a lot more questions soon (and hopefully some answers as well!)

Comment: Awesome. I definitely need more aviation shirts to show my aviation pride. Stickers I could throw on my backpack to show more pride.

Comment: Cool! My wife and kids will look at me and scratch their heads every time I wear it. The only drawback is that I might run into an actual pilot and he may start speaking in acronyms to me, and I'll just have to shake my head and mumble, "no hablos pilotese".

Comment: I know what my new flying shirt is gonna look like. Aviation geek level: unknown.

Comment: Is it available for purchase? I dont mind contributing some funds to stackexchange for this t shirt!! :)

Comment: It is not, @vasin1987. We closed the Stack Shop a while back, and I don't believe we have any intentions of bringing it back.

Comment: @JNat Just out of curiosity, when are they going to show up and is there anyway to track that?  I know, gift horse in the mouth and all, but I'm honestly just curious...

Comment: This swag is currently being produced, and it should be shipped in the next two weeks or so. Unfortunately, since we send them in batches, we're not gonna be providing every single user with a tracking number. You can, however, contact me via email if a reasonable period of time has gone by since I update you to let you know it's been shipped, and you still don't have it, @JayCarr.

Comment: Surely!  Thanks for the update!

Comment: Swag arrived today! Thanks :)

Comment: It has arrived yesterday! Thank you very much!

Comment: My horde of SE swag just got a little bigger. Thanks.

Comment: Mine got here too, thank you sir!

Comment: My stuff arrived yesterday, thanks!

Comment: Thank you guys! Mine arrived today! Frankly, my first shipment from USA!

Answer (score 29):

You guys are awesome.  This site took a while to get out of Area 51, but ever since early beta it has been a really great place.

Huge thanks to all of the moderators and users who have shaped this site into what it is today!

Comment: Thank you Sponge Bob for taking the initiative of proposing this site in [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation). It's been a pleasure to see it grow and to be able to contribute to it.

Comment: Are you actually Sponge Bob? The guy from the cartoon?